# How to get current DB connection name in Cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp

I have two(default and test) db connections in my database.php:

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->default = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'driver' => 'mysql',
                'persistent' => false,
                'encoding' => 'utf8',
                'prefix' => 'shaufel_',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'database' => 'db',
                'login' => 'root', /*** replace this ***/
                'password' => 'root', /*** replace this ***/
        );

        //test db
        $this->test = $this->default;
        $this->test['database'] = $this->test['database'].'_test';
    }
```

How can I get the current DB connection NAME in my Model ? That means for example : `if(current_db is testDB) do something`. I use Cakephp 2.9.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it by myself: `$this->getDataSource()->config['database']`